# Receive mails on openshift with custom domain

Tags: email, openshift

I’m setting up a server on openshift. I’m on the Bronze Plan and have a pretty common setup, I assume. Tomcat 7 with a MySQL database, scalable cartridge, so nothing fancy. I’ve been able to setup the [custom domain](http://speedapp.io) and I am aware of the missing SSL certificate. That stuff is pretty well documented.

But I could not figure out how to get mails working. I’m not talking about sending mails from the application itself, I’ve seen questions covering that topic. I mean mail in general, all mails from and to the domain (I’m more concerned with to the domain for now). I for example need a working *info@speedapp.io* mail address.

Sorry if that is bluntly obvious to anyone else. But I’m coming from a shared Tomcat hosting provider, where the web frontend for mails was already configure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Your question may be better suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server administration

Comment: You are right this is not a programming question and I am aware of that. But the OpenShift website recommends this very tag on on Stackoverflow, so I assumed this is the place to ask questions.

Comment: @AdrianB. True, they link to Stack Overflow, ***but*** however you should probably re-read the headings they have there: http://puu.sh/epHxp/a18073de9b.png. As their page says, Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sign up for email services at a third party host, you can not use OpenShift to host your email.

Comment: Probably a good idea to mention that the OP might need to edit the DNS for their domain so that mail is forwarded to their provider.